# Regex don't match over sentence breaks

Tags: regex

I want to match certain words in the context of other words, like if I wanted to try and capture a filling when we're talking about sandwiches I could do:

`(?:sandwich|toastie).{0,100}(ham|cheese|pickle)`

Which would match something like `Andy sat down to enjoy his sandwich which, unusally for him, was filled with delicious ham`

However this would also capture across "context breaks" such as end-of-sentence punctuation or line breaks e.g. `Victorians enjoyed a good sandwich after work. They also enjoyed cheese rolling.`. In this context I'd want to negate the match as it crosses a sentence.

So I tried to do `(?:sandwich|toastie)(?:\w\. ){0}.{0,100}(ham|cheese|pickle)` but that doesn't work. What I'm imagining is something like `[^\w\. ]` but that isn't right either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you are trying to reject the sample string, you need to use a [tempered greedy token](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#tempered_greed), instead of the way you are writing, and need to write your regex as this,

```
(?:sandwich|toastie)(?:(?!\w\. ).){0,100}(ham|cheese|pickle)
```

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/kiUOo1/1)**

So basically, as you were trying to negate `(?:\w\. )` pattern so the match fails, you need to write `(?:(?!\w\. ).)` instead of just `.` which would fail the match and the words from those two parenthesis will not get matched across two different sentences.

Answer (score 1):

You could make use of a [tempered greedy token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30900794/tempered-greedy-token-what-is-different-about-placing-the-dot-before-the-negat) with a negated character class to assert what is on the right is not any of the listed words, a dot followed by a space or for example a newline:

```
(?:sandwich|toastie)(?:(?!(?:ham|cheese|pickle|\w\. +|(?:\r?\n|\r))).){1,100}(?:ham|cheese|pickle)
```

**Explanation**

- `(?:sandwich|toastie)` Match one of the options
- `(?:` Non capturing group

  - `(?!` Negative lookahead to prevent over matching, assert what follows is not

    - `(?:ham|cheese|pickle|\w\. |(?:\r?\n|\r))` Match any of the options
  - `).` Close negative lookahead and match any character
- `){1,100}` Close non capturing group and repeat 1 - 100 times
- `(?:ham|cheese|pickle)` match one of the options

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/uNIieO/1)

You might consider using word boundaries `\b` for `\b(?:sandwich|toastie)\b` and `\b(?:ham|cheese|pickle)\b` to prevent the words being part of a larger word.